# Finite Difference Method Rearranging the Equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

The image shows the question. I need to find a way to rearrange the equation so that MATLAB outputs a full U vector of size (1,10^6) with non-NaN values.
I'd appreciate any help.

[image]